# Installing Graphics Driver

Tags: system-installation

Please tell me how to Install Graphics driver in Ubuntu 16.04.

My netbook specifications:

- Acer aspire one d271
- Graphics- Integrated,Intel GMA 3150
- Ram- 2GB

I can't even play the video of 480p it just hangs.
I am a new user so please tell me from the beginning.

Comment: How to install the Intel VGA driver in Linux through codes...I have downloaded the driver..How to run or Install?

Answer (score 0):

The Intel graphics are built in. Its your RAM thats low but again, video should not hang. Try turning off other applications when you run video. Also make sure your system has latest updates.